# Compile a maven dependency with two different jdk

Tags: java, maven

I saw many similar questions, but no one asked to mine, so I will try to explain what I want to do: 
I have a Maven project and in this project I have a jdk.min.version=1.8. The problem is that I also use a dependency that can only compile on jdk 1.5! So I want to know if it is possible to compile the project with two different jdk?

Comment: Why not fix the root of the problem: fix the dependency so that it also compiles on JDK 8? (I wonder why it compiles only on JDK 5).

Comment: You do not compile dependencies, they are already compiled. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Java is backward compatible language. Just use java8. It will include what do you want in java5

Comment: The dependency is an API, and I use it to retrieve some information. I build the project with Hudson and there is an error with this API. I discovered that the error is produced by this dependency. Here is what I see : [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project projetzero-java: Unable to register extension org.sonar.plugins.catcher.batch.CatcherSensor: br/eti/kinoshita/testlinkjavaapi/util/TestLinkAPIException: br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.util.TestLinkAPIException

Comment: Is you Hudson running with Java 8 ? Have you configured Maven to use toolchains ? The problem is located based on your sonarqube scan...sonar-maven-plugin:3.2 required Java 8..

Comment: I haven't configured Maven to use toolchains and when I try to change the Hudson jdk, the job fails. Currently we use jdk 7_u76 on Hudson.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it wasn't yhe jdk but in pom.xml: I had a provided in the dependency so I deleted it and added two dependecies and it worked.